# Render multiple subtemplates that append to the same block(s)

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So here's my issue. I have a list of options in my CMS and when I click on one of them, the content in the CMS's panel changes by making the current panel invisible and making the panel corresponding to the option visible. Now, I want those options to be modular and in separate files.

I would like to have a main CMS template that defines a block for options and a block for the panel. Then, each of those options would have it's separate jade file that extends the main template and appends to those blocks.

This would allow me to easilly add new options and render the ones I want selectively in my code. So how can I render multiple templates so that their appendages get added together without making them extend each other in some weird way?

I should also note that includes would be just fine here except that they're compile time so I can't include an array of them.

Here's a code example:

cms-layout.jade

```
block options

block panel
```

option1.jade

```
extends cms-layout

append options
    | Option1
append panel
    div
        | This is the panel for option1
```

option2.jade

```
extends cms-layout

append options
    | Option2
append panel
    div
        | This is the panel for option2
```

And I'd like a way to render both the option1 template and the option2 template with the resulting jade looking like this

```
block options
    | Option1
    | Option2
block panel
    div
        | This is the panel for option1
    div
        | This is the panel for option2
```

Comment: You need to show us some code, or make more clear that this is strictly about programming.

Comment: @TheHippo There. I've added a code example. I was posting from my phone so I couldn't add the code earlier and I thought the wording was descriptive enough.

Answer (score 0):

So the way I ended up doing it is removing the blocks and doing `jade.compile` for each of the separate option jade files on the server. Then I passed that compiled HTML as a string to the CMS's template and inserted it in the desired place(s) using the `!=` operator.

It's pretty sad that this kind of functionality isn't available by default.